# openxlsx format cells as number with comma, and 0 values are replaced with a dash

Tags: r, openxlsx

I am trying to code a workbook script to match a format that auto changes any 0 value into a dash in much the same way clicking the "," in Excel would do. I tried to use numFmt = 'COMMA' however that was unable to produce the dashes. I tried a few custom formats however with no luck. Is there a code that can give me commas, no decimal places, and replace 0s with dashes? My current code is as follows.

```
    addStyle(wb, sheet = "Sheet Name", style = createStyle(numFmt = "#,0"), rows = 4:15, cols = 2:17, gridExpand = T)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is more of an Excel question than R. In Excel custom type works like

```
positive number; negative number; zero
```

Hence if you want to convert zero to a dash then this has to be:

```
#,##0;-#,##0;-
```

So based on your code it will be:

```
 addStyle(wb, sheet = "Sheet Name", style = createStyle(numFmt = "#,##0;-#,##0;-"), rows = 4:15, cols = 2:17, gridExpand = T)
```